# modbus-tk for Modbus RTU, read/write multiple registers (fn code 23), returns exception code 1

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tk

I am using `modbus-tk` to serially communicate with a device via Modbus RTU over a RS-485 network.

I am trying to figure out how to use function 23, `READ_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS`.  This is my first time using function 23.  Here is my current implementation:

```py
response = modbus_master.execute(
    slave=SLAVE_NUM,
    function_code=cst.READ_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS,
    starting_address=2,
    quantity_of_x=1,
    output_value=[1],
)
```

While running this command, I get the following error: `Modbus Error: Exception code = 1`

I looked up this exception code on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Exception_responses), and see:

> Function code received in the query is not recognized or allowed by slave

**Do you think this means my device truly does not support this function code?  Or do I have a syntax problem/am mis-using this function?**

I have placed my full script below.

---

**Full Code Example**

Input

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import time
from collections import namedtuple
from logging import Logger

from serial import Serial
from modbus_tk.modbus_rtu import RtuMaster
import modbus_tk.defines as cst  # cst = constants
from modbus_tk.utils import create_logger


PORT = "COM3"
SLAVE_NUM = 1
MODBUS_MASTER_TIMEOUT_SEC = 5.0

ModbusHoldingReg = namedtuple(
    "ModbusHoldingRegister", ["name", "address", "last_read_value", "to_write_value"]
)
shutdown_delay = ModbusHoldingReg("shutdown delay", 2, 0, None)  # sec

logger = create_logger(name="console")  # type: Logger

serial_ = Serial(PORT)
modbus_master = RtuMaster(serial_)
modbus_master.set_timeout(MODBUS_MASTER_TIMEOUT_SEC)
modbus_master.set_verbose(True)
# Sleep some time per [1]
# [1]: https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/73#issuecomment-284800980
time.sleep(2.0)

# Read/write from/to multiple registers
response = modbus_master.execute(
    slave=SLAVE_NUM,
    function_code=cst.READ_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS,
    starting_address=shutdown_delay.address,
    quantity_of_x=1,
    output_value=[1],
)  # type: tuple
print(response)
```

Output

```py
2020-01-31 10:43:24,885 INFO    modbus_rtu.__init__     MainThread      RtuMaster COM3 is opened
2020-01-31 10:43:26,890 DEBUG   modbus.execute  MainThread      -> 1-23-0-2-0-1-0-23-0-1-2-0-1-55-131
2020-01-31 10:43:31,933 DEBUG   modbus.execute  MainThread      <- 1-151-1-143-240
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModbusError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f42d200d6c09> in <module>
     37     starting_address=shutdown_delay.address,
     38     quantity_of_x=1,
---> 39     output_value=[1],
     40 )  # type: tuple
     41 print(response)

c:\path\to\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\utils.py in new(*args, **kwargs)
     37             ret = fcn(*args, **kwargs)
     38         except Exception as excpt:
---> 39             raise excpt
     40         finally:
     41             if threadsafe:

c:\path\to\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\utils.py in new(*args, **kwargs)
     35             lock.acquire()
     36         try:
---> 37             ret = fcn(*args, **kwargs)
     38         except Exception as excpt:
     39             raise excpt

c:\path\to\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\modbus.py in execute(self, slave, function_code, starting_address, quantity_of_x, output_value, data_format, expected_length)
    312                 # the slave has returned an error
    313                 exception_code = byte_2
--> 314                 raise ModbusError(exception_code)
    315             else:
    316                 if is_read_function:

ModbusError: Modbus Error: Exception code = 1
```

---

**Device Specifics**

- Device: SST Sensing's [OXY-LC-485](https://www.sstsensing.com/product/oxy-lc-oxygen-sensor-interface-electronics/)
- Modbus RTU, `9600/8-N-1`
- [User Guide](https://www.sstsensing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/UG-004_OXY-LC-User-Guide.pdf) (section 7.1.2.1 contains set of input registers)
- Device is plugged into Windows machine that I run this Python script

**Packages**

I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

```py
pyserial==3.4
modbus-tk==1.1.0
```

Comment: You are not the [only one](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/121) to have issues with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to the answer from @maxy; the [modbus spec](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf) states that exception code 1 (ILLEGAL FUNCTION) means:

> The function code received in the query is not an allowable action for
>   the server (or slave). This may be because the function code is only
>   applicable to newer devices, and was not implemented in the unit
>   selected. It could also indicate that the server (or slave) is in the
>   wrong state to process a request of this type, for example because it
>   is unconfigured and is being asked to return register values.

So, in this case, I'd say that the device does not support this command.

However given that another user has reported an issue with this command I thought it was worth checking the encoding:

```
1- Slave ID
23- Function Code
0, 2- Read Starting Address
0, 1- Quantity to Read
0, 23- Write Starting Address
0, 1 - Quantity to write
2, Write Byte Count
0,1, - Write Registers value
55,131 - CRC (have not checked)
```

This looks correct to me with one exception; it's not clear where the "Write Starting Address" comes from (and suspicious that it's the same as the function code). Looking at the [source](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/master/modbus_tk/modbus.py#L262):

```py
pdu = struct.pack(
    ">BHHHHB",
    function_code, starting_address, quantity_of_x, defines.READ_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS,
    len(output_value), byte_count
)
```

This looks wrong to me (`defines.READ_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS` will always be 23). The code was changed to this in commit [dcb0a2f115d7a9d63930c9b4466c4501039880a3](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/commit/dcb0a2f115d7a9d63930c9b4466c4501039880a3); previously it was:

```py
pdu = struct.pack(
    ">BHHHHB",
    function_code, starting_address, quantity_of_x, starting_addressW_FC23,
    len(output_value), byte_count
)
```

This makes more sense to me (you need a way to pass in the address to start writing and the current interface does not seem to provide this). I have added a note re this to the [github issue](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/121).

So in conclusion your issue is probably due to the device but even if the device supported the command I don't think it would work due to a bug in modbus-tk.

Answer (score 2):

Your debug output helpfully contains the following trace:

```
-> 1-23-0-2-0-1-0-23-0-1-2-0-1-55-131
<- 1-151-1-143-240
```

Consider the following:

- The second byte is 23, so the correct function code was sent.
- You actually got an "illegal function code" on the wire, which must have been generated by the device on purpose. You don't get a CRC error or "illegal address" or "illegal value".
- It's possible (but I guess somewhat unlikely) that the device supports code 23, but only for some addresses.

The only thing left that could have been wrong on *your* side is that the library botched the encoding of the actual request. I haven't checked the other bytes, but as [commented by Brits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60013544/modbus-tk-for-modbus-rtu-read-write-multiple-registers-fn-code-23-returns-ex/60021612#comment106139591_60013544), there might be a bug in modbus-tk with the encoding. It's possible that the person implementing the slave decided to respond with "illegal function code" to a malformed request.

It seems also plausible to me that they just didn't bother to implement this function code. For example, [simplymodbus](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/FAQ.htm#FC) doesn't even list it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the rigor of @maxy's answer, then on @Brits's answer, I decided to investigate further.  The goal was to identify if the root cause was a `modbus-tk` bug, or if my device doesn't support function code 23.

In [modbus-tk Issue #121](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/121), the OP mentions that `pymodbus` worked with function code 23, read/write multiple registers.

---

So I installed `pymodbus==2.3.0`, and then gave it a whirl.  Here is the code I used:

Input

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import sys
import logging
from collections import namedtuple

from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusResponse, ExceptionResponse
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
from pymodbus.register_read_message import ReadWriteMultipleRegistersResponse


log = logging.getLogger()
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


ModbusHoldingReg = namedtuple(
    "ModbusHoldingRegister", ["name", "address", "last_read_value", "to_write_value"]
)

sensor_mode = ModbusHoldingReg("sensor on, off, and standby enum", 0, None, None)


PORT = "COM3"
SLAVE_NUM = 1
BAUD_RATE = 9600


with ModbusSerialClient(
    method="rtu", port=PORT, baudrate=BAUD_RATE, strict=False
) as modbus_client:
    regs_to_write = [0, 1, 3]
    response = modbus_client.readwrite_registers(
        read_address=sensor_mode.address,
        read_count=len(regs_to_write),
        write_address=sensor_mode.address,
        write_registers=regs_to_write,
        unit=SLAVE_NUM,
    )  # type: ModbusResponse

    if response.isError():
        response: ExceptionResponse
        print(
            f"Exception!  Original function code = {response.original_code}, "
            f"exception_code = {response.exception_code}."
        )
    else:
        response: ReadWriteMultipleRegistersResponse
        print(f"Success!  response.registers = {response.registers}.")
```

Output

```
Current transaction state - IDLE
Running transaction 1
SEND: 0x1 0x17 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x3 0x6 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x3 0x5d 0xce
New Transaction state 'SENDING'
Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
RECV: 0x1 0x97 0x1 0x8f 0xf0
Getting Frame - 0x97 0x1
Factory Response[151]
Frame advanced, resetting header!!
Adding transaction 1
Getting transaction 1
Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
Original function code = 23, exception code = 1.
```

---

**Conclusion**

One can see that the device responded with exception code 1, `Illegal Function`.  So I believe this device does not support function code 23.

I will circle back if I ever find a device that supports fn code 23.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but I know that my slave is compliant with Function Code 23, it is a wago 750-362.
I can read the datas but it seems the function writes to the wrong address. I do not have function code error.

This is the command I send:

```
inputExt = master.execute(1, cst.READ_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS, 0, 5, output_value=[32767,32767,32767,32767,0x00ff])
```

This is what I see with a wireshark capture:

```
Modbus/TCP
    Transaction Identifier: 35394
    Protocol Identifier: 0
    Length: 21
    Unit Identifier: 1
Modbus
    .001 0111 = Function Code: Read Write Register (23)
    Read Reference Number: 0
    Read Word Count: 5
    Write Reference Number: 23
    Write Word Count: 5
    Byte Count: 10
    Data: 7fff7fff7fff7fff00ff
```

Why the Write reference Number, supposed to be the address where we write and the same as we read, is 23 and not 0? The read reference is OK.

Comment: I am not sure where the write reference number comes from @Testor.  Perhaps it could be useful to post your observations inside the Github issue linked in Brits answer.  Aside from your question, I have one suggestion.  So that you don't have to use Wireshark, modbus-tk has an integrated logger for debugging.  Feel free to look at code samples provided in the original question for how to get it.

Comment: "it seems the function writes to the wrong address" - that is correct. modbus-tk appears to be using the function code (23) as the 'Write Starting Address' (so it's sending the function code twice). This appears to be a bug in [modbus-tk](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/121).